# How to use subplot, imshow, or figure in a loop, to show all the images?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, subplot, imshow

Basically, I want to loop over all frames of video, subtract each frame from background image and display the result i.e **subtractedImg** either using subplot or figure.

```
vidObj = VideoReader('test3.mp4');
width = vidObj.Width;
height = vidObj.Height;

subtractedImg = zeros([width height 3]);
videoFrames = [];
k = 1;
while hasFrame(vidObj)
    f = readFrame(vidObj);
    f=uint8(f);
    videoFrames = cat(numel(size(f)) + 1, videoFrames, f);
    k = k+1;
end
backgroundImg = median(videoFrames,4);
i=1;
```

**Problem here**  subplot which I have used here, in this loop does not show output. Only one figure is displayed with title "last one".

```
while hasFrame(vidObj)
    frame = readFrame(vidObj);

    subtractedImg=imabsdiff(frame,backgroundImg);
    figure(i); imshow(subtractedImg);
    % subplot(5,5,i),imshow(subtractedImg); 
    %uncommenting above line does not work, subplot not shown
    if(i < 20)
    i= i+1;
    end

end %end while

subplot(1,2,1),imshow(subtractedImg),title('last one');
```

How do I show each image using subplot? For example using 5x5 subplot, If I want to display 25 subtracted images, why **subplot(5,5,i),imshow(subtractedImg);** is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make one figure and a new subplot for each frame:

```
figure(1);clf;
for ct = 1:size(videoFrames,4)        
    subtractedImg=imabsdiff(videoFrames(:,:,:,ct),backgroundImg);
    subplot(5,5,ct);imshow(subtractedImg); 
    if(ct == 25)
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: did you try drawnow? (see solution below) You need that if you want to see things happen during the construction of the image. if you only want to see the end result it is not needed.

Comment: Also, you can just read the frames once. They are stored in videoFrames. So in the loop you can do for ct = 1:size(videoFrames,4). and in the loop call imabsdiff(videoframes(:,:,:,ct),backgroundImg);

Comment: I changed the loop as you suggested. Thanks alot. Now how do I show the result of imabsdiff for each frame in the array using subplot?

Comment: I cannot use imabsdiff, but if I replace that line with subtractedImg=abs(videoFrames(:,:,:,ct)-backgroundImg); it works for me. I use matlab 2016b.

Comment: How to display each subtracted image in figure? I used  subplot(5,5,i), subimage(sub); but it only displays image at location 1..

Comment: above here i used subplot(5,5,ct);imshow(subtractedImg);

Comment: Shouldn't it create 5 rows and 5 columns.? It shows only one row and one column and updates it, if I use drawnow.

Comment: Without drawnow it create 5 rows and 5 columns. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do here is to remove the call for `figure` inside the loop. Just one call to the figure before the loop is fine. You can use `clf` at each iteration to clear the current figure's content.

Then, you may want to add a `drawnow` command after the plot commands to refresh the figure at each iteration.

Finally, you may (or not) want to add a `pause` to wait for user input between frames. Note that if you use `pause` then `drawnow` is not required.